# KeyError at / 'login'

Tags: python, django, сессия

Код ниже должен проверить, есть ли в сессиях поле login, тип авторизован пользователь или нет и соотв-но, если есть, вывести мне на страницу, данные с модели(таблицы). Но я получаю такую ошибку..

```
def index(request):
if not request.session['login']:
    HttpResponseRedirect("auth/")
else:
    allAccesses = Accesses.objects.all();
return render(request, "index.html", {'Accesses': allAccesses})
```

Ошибка в подробностях

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 'login'
Exception Location: C:\env\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py in __getitem__, line 55
Python Executable:  C:\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\ecosystems',
'C:\\Python37\\python37.zip',
'C:\\Python37\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python37\\lib',
'C:\\Python37',
'C:\\env',
'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 18 Feb 2019 08:36:27 +0000
```

Comment: Проверка наличия ключа в словаре делается через `if ключ in словарь` (или `not in`)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Но зачем? Ведь [можно просто](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator):

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {'Accesses': Accesses.objects.all()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно как описано ниже, или же 
`if not request.session.get('login'):`
так не будет падать `KeyError`